# Manipulate wordpress REST API search query

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to add a custom field to be included into my search query. That's done via `meta_query`, I am fully aware of that but the issue is, I don't know, where to hang into to manipulate the query args to my needs.

So I am looking for a filter, to to get into REST API search request (`/wp/v2/search`), any clue?

Comment: Are you saying about this endpoint /wp/v2/search ?

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement the following hook:

```php
add_filter( 'rest_post_search_query', 'rest_search_add_custom_field_cb', 10, 2 );
function rest_search_add_custom_field_cb( $query_args, $request ) {
    // filter...

    return $query_args;
}
```

You can modify the search query and include additional params like meta query, etc.

The return value of this filter will be used by WordPress in the following context:

```php
...
$query->query( $query_args );
...
```